# How to upload a stream to Azure blob with a new name

Tags: c#, image, azure, stream, blob

I want to download an Azure blob into stream and then convert stream to image for resizing and then upload new image to Azure blob with a new name. now I can resize the image and upload the stream but I can't upload the stream with new name to Azure.
This is my code:

```
Stream stream = blockBlob.OpenRead();

Image newImage;          
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream);
newImage = new Bitmap(image, 20, 20);

var ms = new MemoryStream();
newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
ms.Position = 0;

blockBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
```

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually pretty simple. What you could need to do is create an  instance of `CloudBlockBlob` with new blob name and upload the content there. Assuming you wish to upload the new file in the same container, this is what you could do:

```
        Stream stream = blockBlob.OpenRead();

        Image newImage;
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(stream);
        newImage = new Bitmap(image, 20, 20);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        newImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
        ms.Position = 0;

        var newBlob = blockBlob.Container.GetBlockBlobReference("new-blob-name.png");
        newBlob.UploadFromStream(ms);
```

Comment: Now how do you do it without a memory stream? Upload should return a stream which we can write into... where is that api?